# Form: I don't get errors when I submit wrong data

Tags: forms, symfony, silex

I have this controller code that validate a form (I'm using it for an ajax reques). The problem: I dont get any error when I submit wrong data, as you can see in the output belower:

```
$app->post('/contacto', function (Request $request) use ($app) {


    $form = $app['form.factory']->createBuilder('form', $data)
        ->add('Nombre', 'text', array(
            'constraints' => new Assert\NotBlank(array('message' => 'El campo Nombre es obligatorio'))
        ))
        ->add('Email', 'text', array(
            'required' => false,
            'constraints' => new Assert\Email(array('message' => 'Has introducido un email no válido. Revísalo, por favor.')),
        ))
        ->add('Telefono', 'text', array(
            'label' => 'Teléfono',
            'constraints' => array(
                new Assert\Regex(array('pattern' => "/^(?:\d\s*){8}\d$/", 'message' => 'El teléfono debe tener 9 dígitos')),
                new Assert\NotBlank(array('message' => 'El campo Teléfono es obligatorio')),
            )))
            ->add('Texto', 'textarea', array(
                'constraints' => new Assert\NotBlank(array('message' => 'El campo Texto es obligatorio')),
                'attr' => array('cols' => '76', 'rows' => '8'),
            ))
            ->getForm();

    $post = $request->request->get('form');

    $form->bind($post);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $data = $form->getData();

         $app['mailer']->send($message);

        $my_array = array('Gracias, hemos recibido tu mensaje, te contactaremos lo antes posible');

        return new Response('true');
    } else {
        var_dump($form->getData());
        var_dump($form->getErrors());
        die("jfklas");
        return new Response(json_encode($form));
    }
});
```

---

```
array(4) {
  ["Nombre"]=>
  string(8) "fasdfasd"
  ["Email"]=>
  string(5) "fasdf"
  ["Telefono"]=>
  string(7) "9999999"
  ["Texto"]=>
  string(7) "fasdfas"
}
array(0) {
}
jfklas
```

Comment: do the assert not blanks work?

Comment: try check output of `$form->getErrorsAsString()` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$form->getErrors()` return only returns errors of the form itself, and not errors from child fields. You can get errors if specify field, example with `$form['Telefono']->getErrors()` or using `$form->getErrorsAsString()`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use getErrors you need to add error_bubbling to your form items

```
    ->add('Nombre', 'text', array(
        'error_bubbling' => true, 'constraints' => new Assert\NotBlank(array('message' => 'El campo Nombre es obligatorio'))
    ))
```